# MySQL query to match date and null between two tables

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have two `MySQL`-tables like this:

```
desc students;
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                     | Type          | Null | Key | Default |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| student_id                | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| student_firstname         | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |
| student_lasttname         | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+

desc studentabsence;
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                     | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| student_absence_id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| student_id                | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |
| student_absence_startdate | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |
| student_absence_enddate   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |
| student_absence_type      | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
```

Then I have this `MySQL`- query to list students.

Query:

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname,
 a.student_absence_startdate, a.student_absence_enddate, a.student_absence_type
FROM students s LEFT JOIN studentabsence a ON a.student_id = s.student_id
```

Whenever a student has absence information this is displayed in the columns

`a.student_absence_startdate` 
`a.student_absence_enddate`
`a.student_absence_type`

Sometimes a student has two or more rows in the table `studentabsence` then he is listed two times.

**My question** is if there is any way to be more specific in the query. I would like to list all students from `db.students` **and** if there is a row in `db.studentabsence` with a **date** between startdate and enddate (for example 2012-07-30) list the student one time with this absence information. Only if there is a match on date.

So something like...

```
... WHERE (a.student_absence_startdate OR a.student_absence_enddate) IS NULL OR
   '2012-07-30' BETWEEN a.student_absence_startdate AND
    a.student_absence_enddate ...
```

It's kinda hard to explain so let me know if you need more information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can arrange it with a JOIN on a subselect/subview :

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname,
a.student_absence_startdate, a.student_absence_enddate, a.student_absence_type
FROM students s 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM studentabsence a1 WHERE ('2012-07-30' BETWEEN a1.student_absence_startdate AND a1.student_absence_enddate) ) a 
ON a.student_id = s.student_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use parameters with default values (01/01/1900 00:00:00), like this:

```
AND  ( a.student_absence_startdate >= @P_startdate  OR  @P_startdate = '01/01/1900 00:00:00' )  
AND  ( a.student_absence_enddate <= @P_enddate  OR  @P_enddate = '01/01/1900 00:00:00' )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I went with @aleroot suggestion!